# Different contents for the same wav file

Tags: python, audio, numpy, scipy, wav

I'm trying to open a wav file in python and inspect its contents. I followed 3 different approaches : use scipy.io.wavfile , use wave, directly read the contents from the file.

Approach 1: using the wave module

```
>>> import wave
>>> import numpy as np
>>> wf = wave.open('test.wav','rb')
>>> f = wf.readframes(160)
>>> data = np.fromstring(f)
>>> print data
[  2.82596915e+103   7.66148517e+283   1.55915666e-083  -7.82893925e-042
  -2.23287375e-293  -4.58038073e+011   8.93193919e-027   1.52567878e+292
   3.88980986e+055  -3.00054045e+099  -1.41604458e-280  -7.16366832e-116
   5.91987737e-176   3.41189939e+258   3.87973542e+168  -4.11714940e+254
  -1.03609882e-226  -4.36842462e-213  -7.51023721e+282   2.32154921e+185
   2.13137319e+248   1.08450144e-203  -1.69687232e-135  -5.92443342e-274
  -1.67041051e+126   5.56090419e+077   1.73494487e+289   4.44998489e-052
  -2.26308769e-013  -3.43049660e-294  -2.02115225e-018   1.52038226e-057
   2.80968683e+288   2.21954395e+082  -9.30599671e+131  -2.27150239e-272
  -1.49931560e-139   1.28957321e-209   1.00441910e+246   6.07714540e+188]
>>> wdata = np.array(data,dtype='int32')
>>> print wdata
[-2147483648 -2147483648           0           0           0 -2147483648
           0 -2147483648 -2147483648 -2147483648           0           0                                                                                                                        
           0 -2147483648 -2147483648 -2147483648           0           0                                                                                                                        
 -2147483648 -2147483648 -2147483648           0           0           0                                                                                                                        
 -2147483648 -2147483648 -2147483648           0           0           0                                                                                                                        
           0           0 -2147483648 -2147483648 -2147483648           0                                                                                                                        
           0           0 -2147483648 -2147483648]
```

Approach 2 : Using the scipy.io.wavfile module. Continues from the previous approach

```
>>> import scipy                    
>>> from scipy.io.wavfile import read
>>> fs,wavdata=read("test.wav")
>>> print fs
11025
>>> print wavdata
[    0  7940 15384 ..., 31997 30888 27848]
```

Approach 3 : Directly read from the file

```
>>> print np.fromstring(open('test.wav').read(160),dtype='int32')
[ 1179011410       80036  1163280727   544501094          16       65537
       11025       22050     1048578  1635017060       80000   520355840
  1432960024  1992649059  2061532345  1622700376   784222732  -247394173
 -1218063638 -1888771989 -2094234250 -1783920464 -1034245812   -29761725
   981867849  1751864346  2090366516  1914010417  1266246103   306655331
  -728370426 -1584154406 -2049667020 -2010414313 -1475963714  -577978161
   462290033  1388787954  1973184366  2071690352]
```

In approach 1 and approach 3, I had to convert the data into int32. Scipy does this by default in approach 2. Then why would i be getting different outputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the same result. modify `fromstring` in the **first approach** as

```
if w.getsampwidth() == 1:
    data = np.fromstring(f, dtype=np.int8)
elif w.getsampwidth() == 2:
    data = np.fromstring(f, dtype=np.int16)
elif w.getsampwidth() == 4:
    data = np.fromstring(f, dtype=np.int32)
```

where `w.getsampwidth()` has **how many byte(s) used for representing samples**

The `np.fromstring` reads bytes as `float64` then convert the values (not bytes) into `int32` by `astype('int32')`. So you need to read bytes corresponding `type` among `int8, 16 and 32`

**Second** approach has no problem.

The wave file(maybe RIFF format) has 44 bytes header. So **the last** doesn't work properly.